# MS SQL Server alias and DNS server

Tags: sql-server, dns

I have a `MS SQL Server` `S` hosting a `MS SQL Server` instance `I`.
I would like another machine `M` to be able to connect to that instance remotely via the TCP port `P`.

I created an alias `A` = `S\I,P` on both `S` and `M` using the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cliconfg.exe` tool.
`S` and `M` can both use the alias `A` properly.

If I wanted another machine `M2` to be able to connect to that `MS SQL Server` instance too, I would need to create an alias on `M2` like I did on machines `S` and `M`.

Is there a way to do it in the `DNS server` (Microsoft DNS Manager)?
I don't see how it could be done because basically:

- I would need the `DNS server` to register the fact that `A` is an alias for `S\I,P`
- and when a client machine `C` on the network uses `A`, I would need the `DNS server` to "resolve" that alias for `C`.

If it cannot be done using a DNS server, is there a way to do it in a centralized way
(that is to say: having some sort of service on the network that "translates" `A` into `S\I,P` when a client machine asks for it) ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do it in the DNS server (Microsoft DNS Manager)?

If you do not have an instance on server S using default port 1433, you can let instance I listen this default port.

This way any client using DNS alias resolving IP of server S could be connected via default port.

> If it cannot be done using a DNS server, is there a way to do it in a centralized way

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cliconfg.exe just create some registry entry in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo

or

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo

You can propagate those registry entries via group policy.